# Pass id from first model into a Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a problem wanting to pass the id of Products in the subqueries.

The first code is what I have so far. The second is the way I want to do with Eloquent, but I can't.

```
      $result = [];

    Product::with(['locals.presentations'])->each(function ($product) use (&$result) {

        $body['id'] = $product->id;
        $body['nombre'] = $product->nombre;
        $sedes = [];
        $product->locals->each(function ($local) use (&$sedes, $product) {
            $presentations = [];
            $local->presentations->each(function ($presentation) use (&$presentations, $local, $product) {

                if ($presentation->local_id == $local->id && $presentation->product_id == $product->id) {
                    $presentations[] = [
                        'local_id' => $presentation->local_id,
                        'product_id' => $presentation->product_id,
                        'presentacion' => $presentation->presentation,
                        'precio_default' => $presentation->price
                    ];
                }
            });

          ...
    });

    return $result;
```

I want transform the previous code into this with Eloquent, but I can't pass the product_id into the subqueries:

```
    $products = Product::with(['locals' => function ($locals) {
        //How to get the id from Product to pass in the $presentations query ??????
        $locals->select('locals.id', 'descripcion')
            ->with(['presentations' => function ($presentations) {
                $presentations
                // ->where('presentations.product_id', $product_id?????)
                ->select(
                    'presentations.local_id',
                    'presentations.product_id',
                    'presentations.id',
                    'presentation',
                    'price'
                );
            }]);
    }])->select('products.id', 'nombre')->get();

    return $products;
```

Product

```
    public function locals()
{

    return $this->belongsToMany(Local::class)->using(LocalProduct::class)
        ->withPivot(['id', 'is_active'])
        ->withTimestamps();

}
```

Local

```
    public function presentations()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        Presentation::class,
        LocalProduct::class,
        'local_id',
        'local_product_id'
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the `has()` method if you have set the relations correctly on the `Product` and `Local` models. This will return ONLY the products which has locals AND presentations.

If you want every product but only the locals and presentations with the product_id equals to the products.id, then you don't have to do anything. The relationship you set in your models already checks if the id matches.

```
$products = Product::has('locals.presentations')
    ->with(['locals' => function ($locals) {
        $locals
            ->select('locals.id', 'descripcion')
            ->with(['presentations' => function ($presentations) {
                $presentations->select(
                    'presentations.local_id',
                    'presentations.product_id',
                    'presentations.id',
                    'presentation',
                    'price'
                );
           }]);
    }])->select('products.id', 'nombre')->get();
```

Comment: I have the same result with your code... :/. I updated my models